# Algorithmic complexity of finding the lowest value in a balanced binary search tree

Tags: big-o, binary-search-tree

I made a function to find the lowest value of a balanced binary tree by choosing the node's left child from the root each time in a loop until the left child is None. For example below , it iterates through `[4, 2, 1]`.
[image]
**My question:** Is the algorithmic complexity of this still `O(log n)` as with insertion since it does not ever visit any right nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a balanced binary tree has height *h = O(log n)*. Therefore, since you visit at most one node on each level, you visit at most *h + 1* nodes, and finding the next vertex to visit (choosing the left one) is an *O(1)* operation. Therefore, your algorithm is also *O(log n)*.